# is there a php wildcard boolean filter function

Tags: php, string, search, filter

Is there a php function that does both wildcard filtering plus boolean AND/OR filtering?

```
$source = "My dog has fleas";
$filter = "*fleas OR Your*";
echo "Result: ".WildcardBooleanSearch($source, $filter);
```

The result should say true or false. In this example it should say true.
I searched the web and found wildcard filtering, and found boolean filtering, but I didn't find both in one.

fnmatch($filter,$source) handles wildcards, but doesn't know what AND and OR mean.  Same limitation with preg_match.
I can't simple explode(' or ',$filter) because there might be nested OR's and AND's.

Closest comparison I can think of is VBA function Application.BuildCriteria

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP preg_match function.  If you're using a simple string search, you may also use strpos.  Here's an example:

```
$source="My dog has fleas";
$filter="fleas or your";
if (strpos($source,$filter)) {
   echo "Found the match";
}
```

You can do much more complex matches using preg_match.

Comment: No that won't work. The word 'or' inside $filter is a boolean OR, not a plain-english 'or'.

Comment: Well, you're right ... that wouldn't work with a boolean or.  You'd be better off using preg_match where you can use regular expressions to match practically anything.

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
echo "Result: " . preg_match( "/(fleas|Your)/", $source );
```

and:

```
echo "Result: " . ( preg_match( "/fleas/", $source ) && preg_match( "/Your/", $source ) );
```

Comment: No that won't work. The result must be calculated using a function call in the form of     WildcardBooleanSearch($source, $filter);

Comment: Well, it's just a matter of how you implement these preg_matches into your function. You can add there more search patters or just leave it like this.